# space in json response not converting to php object

Tags: php, json

Below is my working code but when I am trying to echo "Telecom circle", getting error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'circle' (T_STRING)".

```
if ($_GET['result']):
$rslt = $_GET['result'];
$result = Unirest\Request::get("https://sphirelabs-mobile-number-portability-india-operator-v1.p.mashape.com/index.php?number=$rslt",
array(
"X-Mashape-Key" => "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"Accept" => "application/json"
)
);

echo ($result->body->Operator);
echo($result->body->Telecom circle);
endif;
```

API RESPONSE :

```
{
"Telecom circle": "Delhi NCR",
"Operator": "Vodafone",
"Is MNP": "False"
}
```

Comment: Check this line `$result->body->Telecom circle` try to remove space between Telecom and circle

Comment: not working, I already tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be :

Just used  `$result->body->{'Telecom circle'}` instead of `$result->body->Telecom circle`

```
if ($_GET['result']):
$rslt = $_GET['result'];
$result = Unirest\Request::get("https://sphirelabs-mobile-number-portability-india-operator-v1.p.mashape.com/index.php?number=$rslt",
array(
"X-Mashape-Key" => "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"Accept" => "application/json"
)
);

echo ($result->body->Operator);
echo($result->body->{'Telecom circle'});
endif;
```